# How to add line of text under the whole ggsurvplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add line of text under the whole plot. However, it seems ggsurvplot handles plot and risk-table as two entities. I would like to have it like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGKGA.png)

However, this is added in MS Word and the journal asks to have it embedded in the picture itself and I am unable to do that.

Thank you :-)

```
ggsurvplot(fit = fit, data = dat, pval = TRUE, 
       color = "black", 
       risk.table = T,
       break.time.by = 12, 
       surv.scale = "percent",
       linetype = c("solid","dotted", "dashed"),
       legend.labs = c("Control group", "TMA R-ve", "TMA R+ve"), 
       censor.shape = 124, 
       legend.title = "",
       title = "5-years death-censored graft survival", 
       xlab = "Months from transplantation", 
       ylab = "Survival (%)")
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose there may be multiple approaches to laying out the plot, table, and text caption. Here is one way I thought might be easier to work with.

The `ggsurvplot` object, if you include the risk table, will have two `ggplot` objects contained in it, one for the curve plot, and one for the table (the table itself is a plot).

You can just add to the table plot a caption, and this will appear below the table in the end. If you include `hjust = 0` with `plot.caption` it will be left justified.

Here is an example:

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
ggsurv <- ggsurvplot(fit, risk.table = TRUE)

ggsurv$table <- ggsurv$table +
  theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0)) +
  labs(caption = "Figure 1: 5-years death-censored graft survival")

ggsurv
```

[image: ggsurvplot with figure text below table]